# Issue in execute a method after completion of another method - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two methods as loadTopicPostsFromDB and loadTopicPosts. In the loadTopicPostsFromDB method I am updating the value of a global NSString called strLastTimeStamp which should use in the loadTopicPosts. Thus, I want to execute loadTopicPostsFromDB first and after it finished(global string updated) I want to execute loadTopicPosts method. 
This is how I did it. But, currently loadTopicPosts method executes before updating the global strLastTimeStamp, so always I get a wrong strLastTimeStamp.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

        dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadTopicPostsFromDB) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        });

        dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
            NSLog(@"LoadDBCompleted");

            [self loadTopicPosts];
        });
```

How can I do this, please advice me on what is the wrong in this implementation.

Comment: Did you try with waitUntilDone:YES ???

Comment: Why don't you execute loadTopicPosts method from the last line of loadTopicPostsFromDB??

Comment: @DilumN That cannot be done, because I have some other scenarios to consider as well

Comment: you can use `NSOperationQueue` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

performSelectorOnMainThread: is finished as soon as iOS has put the task into a queue. The selector has most likely not even started running when the call returns. And really, you shouldn't be using performSelectorOnMainThread at all - the function isn't available in Swift, for good reason. The solution is a lot easier (fix the problems yourself):

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{ 
    [self loadTopicsFromDB];
    [self loadTopicPosts];
});
```

You probably want to perform loadTopicsFromDB on a background thread though.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing something using network connection I advice you to use `blocks` to handle the endpoint of the call.

It is pretty simple to write in this code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self loadTopicsFromDB: ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        [self loadTopicPosts];
    }];
});
```